# VxWorks 6.8: setsockopt with IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP returning EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: sockets, multicast, vxworks

I am trying to set up a socket to receive multicast UDP packets on VxWorks 6.8.

```
sin.sin_len = (u_char)sizeof (sin); 
sin.sin_family = AF_INET; 
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

/* UDP port number to match for the received packets */ 
sin.sin_port = htons (mcastPort); 

/* bind a port number to the socket */ 
if (bind(sockDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) != 0) 
    { 
    perror("bind"); 
    status = errno; 
    goto cleanUp; 
    } 

/* fill in the argument structure to join the multicast group */ 
/* initialize the multicast address to join */ 

ipMreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr (mcastAddr); 

/* unicast interface addr from which to receive the multicast packets */ 
ipMreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr (ifAddr); 
printf ("Interface address on which to receive multicast packets: %s\n", ifAddr);     
/* set the socket option to join the MULTICAST group */

int code = setsockopt (sockDesc, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, 
        (char *)&ipMreq, 
        sizeof (ipMreq));
```

The `setsockopt()` call is returning `-1` and `errno` is being set to `49` or `EADDRNOTAVAIL`. On wireshark, when we perform `setsockopt` I can see a properly formed group unsubscribe packet being sent out from the right port/interface. All different combinations of interfaces, ports, and multicast groups give the same result.

I am unable to debug very far into `setsockopt` as there doesnt seem to be anything wrong before the task calls `ipcom_pipe_send` and `ipnet_usr_sock_pipe_recv`, and after the recv call errno is set. I dont know how to debug the relevant `tNetTask` code that may be generating the error.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that there's an issue with the interface index you supplied.  Define `ipMreq` to be a `struct ip_mreq`, which does not have the `imr_ifindex`, instead of a `struct ip_mreqn` and remove the `ipMreq.imr_ifindex = 2;` line.

Comment: Verify both the input once 
1. whether the address really falls in Class D, if (IN_MULTICAST(ntohl(mcastAddr))).   2. Also this normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer, so verify the ifAddr value also.